# Friendly URL Slugs in Phoenix 1.2

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, friendly-url

I'm trying to add slugs for friendly URLs in an older Phoenix 1.2 app.  I have new records writing to the slug and display that in the URL fine, but previous entries are not updating.  Not only that, from the index view, the link has removed the id parameter.

What am I missing to have previous entries use the slug? I have no errors in the app.

**radio.ex**

```
defmodule Radios.Radio do
  use Radios.Web, :model

  schema "radios" do
    field :name, :string
    field :desc, :string
    field :price, :integer
    field :text1, :string
    field :text2, :string
    field :text3, :string
    field :text4, :string
    field :mainimg, :string
    field :mainimg2, :string
    field :slug, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    params = Map.merge(params, slug_map(params))
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :desc, :price, :text1, :text2, :text3, :text4, :mainimg, :mainimg2, :slug])
    |> validate_required([:name, :desc, :price, :text1, :text2, :mainimg])
  end

  # for writing URL as radio.name
  defimpl Phoenix.Param, for: Radios.Radio do
    def to_param(%{slug: slug}) do
      "#{slug}"
    end
  end

      defp slug_map(%{"name" => name}) do
        slug = String.downcase(name) |> String.replace(" ", "-")
        %{"slug" => slug}
      end

    defp slug_map(_params) do
    %{}
    end
end
```

**radio_controller.ex**

```
defmodule Radios.RadioController do
  use Radios.Web, :controller
...
  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    radio = Repo.get_by!(Radio, slug: id)
    render(conn, "show.html", radio: radio)
  end 


...
```

Comment: Do those records have a value in the `slug` column?

Comment: @Dogbert nope, Null.

Comment: Not sure what you want then? If the slug column is `nil` all of them will have the slug `"#{nil}"` which is `""`.

Comment: From following https://elixircasts.io/seo-friendly-urls-with-phoenix shouldn't this code be mapping what's already in column 'name' to 'slug' when edited?